# How to select rows from a growing MySQL table incrementally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that grows very rapidly.  I would like to have an ongoing process (e.g. running every 30 minutes) that selects all the rows that are "new" since the last time the process was run.  The table has an AUTO_INCREMENT column called id, and I thought I could use it to make sure I'm getting all the records.  Here was the approach:

Initialize

```
LAST_ID_SELECTED = 0
```

Run repeatedly, forever:

```
startID = 1 + LAST_ID_SELECTED
nextAutoIncrementID = getQuery("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'")
lastID = nextAutoIncrementID - 1
data = SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id BETWEEN startID AND lastID
LAST_ID_SELECTED = lastID
```

However, I don't think this will actually work:  I'm worried that I can get my (startID, lastID) range and make my select query before all the inserts for the ids <= lastID have been completed.  So I won't actually get all the rows in the range (startID,lastID).

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What if you got the MAX(id) from the underlying table itself?  Have you looked into replication?

Comment: what is the environment where you are running this code?? anyway, when you do "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT..." the records are already there, so why would your last select not work??

Comment: @AlainCollins Would MAX(id) be more reliable?  Is it possible for inserts to happen out of order, with respect to id?  Not sure what you're suggesting with replication. Thanks!